# How to query a child from another child. Firebase(SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

im developing a delivery app. So I have productos and popular products in firebase this way:

- Products

[image: Products]

- PopularProducts(ID of the product as key and true as value)

[image: PopularProducts]

How I can query only the products who are popular using those childs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get array of `productosPopulares` and then get each object.

```
let referenceToProductosPopulares = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "productosPopulares")

referenceToProductosPopulares.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
           let productosPopIds = value.allKeys as! [String]
           // get every object    
           for id in productosPopIds {
               let refToProd = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "productos").child(id)
               refToProd.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                   // your value
               })
           }
        } else {
          print("productosPopulares")
        }
     })
```

Not perfect code. Should make more functions. But this is idea.

Hope it helps

Comment: This answer is not as efficient as mine. You are first downloading the keys of the popular products and then you are making a separate request per product which is bad.

Comment: @Callam in your case with 10000 objects server side will check every object. It's not efficient. In my case it will download full data of only necessary objects. He has array of Id's. He needs to download only items with this id's.

Comment: @Callam I think that the best way depends on full logic of the Gustavo. In future he can use best way for his solution. Anyway. The question was "How to query a child from another child". It's my answer. You don't use this array at all. My answer is better for this question. May be (may be, we can't prove it) the better way for all situatuin will be yours:)

Comment: @Callam and thanks from me. Cz I havent knew that firebase has indexing:)

Answer (score 1):

You can query ordered by the `esPopular` child and only return the children with it equal to `true`.

```
let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "productos")
let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "esPopular").queryEqual(toValue: true)

query.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot)
}) { (error) in
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: In this case you will download every object and then search, as I remember. It is not a good way

Comment: @VladPulichev in this case, the client is not downloading every object. The querying does not take place on the client and so the client only downloads the children with `esPopular` equal to true.

Comment: Well, nevermind, that it will do server, but yes, I wrote mistake. You will not download all data. But server will do same on server side.. For example with 100000 objects server will check every item. That is not efficient.

Comment: Check firebase docs. It's best practice to store array of id's with "true" value.

Comment: @VladPulichev that's what `.indexOn` in the rules is for, you can use it to improve querying performance

Comment: It will not give you same efficient in my opinion:) I'll uparrow your answer, cz it's also correct. But not a good way for mr. Gustavo I think.

Comment: In your case with 10000 objects, you download all the keys first and then download each product one by one. I understand that my solution may be inefficient server side, but with indexing, the performance can be improved. Firebase charges for data transferred and my solution returns the same products transferring less data and making fewer requests. The deciding factor is which solution is faster with a large dataset because as well as saving the creator money, we want to save the user's time.